# Looping over an AngularJS grid

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to loop over an AngularJS grid looking for a row that has an ID I want to delete. I know I need to use the foreach statement, but am unfamiliar with it even after looking at the documentation. An example using the below criteria would be more useful.

How would I accomplish this?

I have the following function that has the grid and row objects.

```
viewModel.viewRow = function (grid, row)
```

I'm trying to compare the row within the grid that has the same ID value as the following:

```
row.entity.CheckDepositHeaderId
```

After I find it, I simply want to remove the row from the grid collection.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the grid to a model (the data parameter in grid options) and remove from there.

row.entity is the object for that row. You can assign the entity an id and use that to search through your model.